# 2E> unable to mount developer disk image, (Error Domain=com.apple.dtdevicekit Code=601

Tags: ios, xcode, nativescript, xcodebuild

Having build issue when running nativescript application in ios platform.
My xcode Version 12.2 (12B45b) and showing error as "The current device configuration is unsupported. This iPhone 4 is running iOS 14.7.1 (18G82), which is not supported by Xcode 12.2."

```js
Project successfully prepared (ios)
Configure firebase
Add iOS crash logging
Building project...
Xcode build...
2022-03-16 12:52:12.267 xcodebuild[3959:55798]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 00008020-000A393E2123002E was NULL
2022-03-16 12:52:12.467 xcodebuild[3959:55798]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 00008020-000A393E2123002E was NULL
2022-03-16 12:52:12.467 xcodebuild[3959:55798]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 00008020-000A393E2123002E was NULL
2022-03-16 12:52:13.621 xcodebuild[3959:55796]  iPhoneConnect: <DVTiOSDevice (0x7ff74baabfe0), Mobile’s iPhone XR, iPhone, 14.7.1 (18G82), 00008020-000A393E2123002E> unable to mount developer disk image, (Error Domain=com.apple.dtdevicekit Code=601 "The current device configuration is unsupported. This iPhone 4 is running iOS 14.7.1 (18G82), which is not supported by Xcode 12.2." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The current device configuration is unsupported. This iPhone 4 is running iOS 14.7.1 (18G82), which is not supported by Xcode 12.2., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=To run on this device, please update to a version of Xcode that supports iOS 14.7.1. You can download Xcode from the Mac App Store or the Apple Developer website., DVTRadarComponentKey=487927, DeviceType=iPhone11,8, NSUnderlyingError=0x7ff74ba2a820 {Error Domain=com.apple.dt.DVTDeviceSupportFilesError Code=2 "Unable to locate ideal DDI for platform: <DVTPlatform:0x7ff74875e810:'com.apple.platform.iphoneos':<DVTFilePath:0x7ff74875e660:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform'>>, version: 14.7.1, build: 18G82" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to locate ideal DDI for platform: <DVTPlatform:0x7ff74875e810:'com.apple.platform.iphoneos':<DVTFilePath:0x7ff74875e660:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform'>>, version: 14.7.1, build: 18G82, DVTRadarComponentKey=487927}}}) {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
    DeviceType = "iPhone11,8";
    NSLocalizedDescription = "The current device configuration is unsupported. This iPhone 4 is running iOS 14.7.1 (18G82), which is not supported by Xcode 12.2.";
    NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion = "To run on this device, please update to a version of Xcode that supports iOS 14.7.1. You can download Xcode from the Mac App Store or the Apple Developer website.";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=com.apple.dt.DVTDeviceSupportFilesError Code=2 \"Unable to locate ideal DDI for platform: <DVTPlatform:0x7ff74875e810:'com.apple.platform.iphoneos':<DVTFilePath:0x7ff74875e660:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform'>>, version: 14.7.1, build: 18G82\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to locate ideal DDI for platform: <DVTPlatform:0x7ff74875e810:'com.apple.platform.iphoneos':<DVTFilePath:0x7ff74875e660:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform'>>, version: 14.7.1, build: 18G82, DVTRadarComponentKey=487927}";
}
```

how to solve this issue?